# visual studio - how to exclude a filter from build (without deleting it)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I added a filter and some `.c` files to my `.vcxproj` through the GUI but they won't build correctly because I'm in the process of adding all the correct environment variables.

Is it possible to temporarily exclude from the build a filter and its children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name says, 'filter' is just view filter and has no effect on build system, thus, there is no easy way. You can only modify project and source files properties ('Excluded from build' of cpp in your case).

But... there is a workaround, which makes you edit all cpp files only once and works for all build configurations.

Create props file (View->Other Windows -> Property manager, right mouse button on your project and 'Add new...') and in User Macros add TempExclude with value 'Yes'

[image: Props]
Now select all problematic files and in `Excluded from Build` type `$(TempExclude)` (Don't forget to select `All Configurations` and `All Platforms`)

[image: sources]

Now you can edit just value of TempExclude in property file to get you files in/out build. If you dont define TempExclude it will include files into build.